# Is the private key included in the CA bundle?

Tags: openssl, certificates, apache-virtualhost

Below you can see my apache2 virtual host SSL config from one of our domains, which works fine:

```
    ...

    # Example SSL configuration
    SSLEngine on
    #SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    #SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/ssl/certs/company/cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/ssl/certs/company/key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/ssl/certs/company/ca-bundle"

    ...
```

I need to upgrade another website to make it use SSL.

But our IT department only gave me the `cert` and the `ca-bundle`, they say that the private key is included in the `ca-bundle`

So I tried to ommit "SSLCertificateKeyFile" but it still does not work this way.

So is the private key really included in the CA bundle?

I've read that it can be included in the certificate itself, but it is highly discouraged.

> "Finally the end-entity certificate's private key can also be added to
> the certificate file instead of using a separate SSLCertificateKeyFile
> directive. This practice is highly discouraged. If it is used, the
> certificate files using such an embedded key must be configured after
> the certificates using a separate key file. If the private key is
> encrypted, the pass phrase dialog is forced at startup time."

[Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html)

Comment: Search in bundle file for `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

Comment: There is only 3x `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`

Comment: So there is no private key in this file.

Comment: Sounds logical. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way (if the bundle is in PAM format) is to search for string:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

also searching only for

```
PRIVATE KEY
```

can be enough